# How to write an Script for TexStudio to auto switch into English language inside of math mode?

Tags: macros, texstudio, scripts

Switching from local keyboard language   to English then backing to local keyboard  language outside of math mode is common in non-English latex users.

How to write an Script for TexStudio to auto switch into English language inside of math mode?

---

### Update:

texstudio have a built in such script (`Configure Texstudio-> Adv. Editor-> Bi-Di->`check last two check boxes) but it is so laggy. sometimes it switches keyboard wrongly. sometimes it switches keyboard rapidly after each keypress.

Posting the source code of this script as answer would suffices.

**KeyBoard Lang: Non-En: -->** [image]

**KeyBoard Lang: En: -->**
[image]

Comment: Could you provide a small example? I'm not quite sure what the problem is.

Comment: @campa: see update